# DLR for MMS with twilio

Tags: twilio, mms

When sending MMS to twilio number the carrier that sent the MMS did not get a DLR message

Is it something that I need to configure in twilio so it will send such a DLR message?

Thanks

Comment: No configuration needed.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only get DLR when you are sending an MMS from a Twilio number to some other carrier.

Official docs - https://www.twilio.com/docs/iot/supersim/api/smscommand-resource#status-values